# How do I determine what category this question belongs in?

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question on Chemistry Stack Exchange titled ["Carbonated Beverage Phenomenon."](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139927/carbonated-beverage-phenomenon) I was wondering whether this question belongs more in the chemistry or physics category. I eventually decided that it fit more in chemistry, because chemistry is about how substances interact with each other. However, there are many other questions that blur the line between chemistry and physics. Is there any definitive way to determine which category a question belongs in?

Comment: No, not really. A good way to find this out is by asking in [chat] or here on meta first. Sometimes that can either lead to giving you similar questions that might already answer it, or further background that will make the question clearer or at least help you include more context. I've noticed that you question has already a down vote, which I'd assume to be due to the basic nature of it.